# OPC UA communication with different PLCs

Tags: plc, opc, opc-ua

I have  a question.
Does OPC UA solve the problem of communicating with for example with all type of PLCs ?
The problem is for us , PLCs are different, and we want to grab data from all ! 
Can OPC UA do anything in here to simplify the process ?

Comment: Currently, very few PLCs exist that incorporate OPC UA natively that you can communicate with them directly with the OPC UA protocol. To my knowledge only some models of Siemens, Omron and some Codesys based incorporate it.

Comment: thanks for your answer , so you think we need to write driver for all models and brands that we want to communicate ?

Comment: In these cases, an OPC UA server is usually installed on a PC that can incorporate the drivers to communicate with many PLC brands. Kepware is one of the best known, but it's not cheap ...
If you want to program your own server you can use one of the SDKs available in the market

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't solve it completely, but it comes close.

Some PLCs now have OPC UA built in, so you can communicate with those quite easily.

Other PLCs do not, but you can use an OPC UA server from either the vendor or a third party like Kepware to communicate with it.

But there will inevitably be some devices out there with no OPC UA option.

In summary though, if you're dealing with common PLCs, then yes OPC UA can help. To consume data all you need is an OPC UA client and you can make either direct connections or connections to another server and let the server worry about "native" communication with the PLC.

Comment: what is the best way to read tags from all PLCs in your opinion ?